# Better way to make money

Tags: watch-dogs

I'm playing Watch Dogs and as far as i know, the only way to make money is by doing missions, selling looted items and/or hacking other phones.

Is there a more efficient way to make some money?

Comment: I don't know of any more efficient way than doing missions or hacking people, but Watch_Dogs _is_ a Ubisoft game, and therefore money is (almost) worthless. Money is only for buying new weapons - some of which are dropped by enemies - or for refilling your ammo. By the end of the game, you'll be virtually a millionaire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way to make money is taking the "more money when hacking accounts" skill AND the "highlight good targets" skill which will highlight targets with lots of money (we're talking thousands upon thousands of $$$ here)

Then, you either drive or walk around slowly, best at crowded areas. Targets will be highlighted and you can just focus on them

Comment: Hmm...thought so. Guess i'll have to do some missions to get skill points. Thanks, man!